# Rails checkboxes for a has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox, has-many-through

A person can compete in various events, but they must enter a partner's name for that event. This association is stored in an entry, which contains a field for the partner's name.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :entries
    has_many :events, :through => :entries

    validates_presence_of :name
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :person
    belongs_to :event

    validates_presence_of :partner_name
end
```

The question is: How do you create a single page form that allows a person to enter themselves in multiple events and input their partners' names? I've tried to implement an `all_entries` method in the person model that will return an array of entry objects for all the available events, and an `all_entries_attributes` method that will update, create, and delete entry objects, but I can't seem to find a good, clean way to do this. I know this is a rather open ended question, but this must be a pattern that someone else in the rails community has encountered before, so I'm hoping there is a good solution to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are still looking for the answer you might want to check out my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174513/rails-has-many-through-form-with-checkboxes-and-extra-field-in-the-join-model) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174513/rails-has-many-through-form-with-checkboxes-and-extra-field-in-the-join-model/9191867#9191867) that I found.

Answer (score 0):

So you want a page in which you can create events for a user, and add people to those events

I won't give you a plain solution because there's some work to an implementation for this, but I will recommend checking out these railscasts about nested model forms

[part1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and [part2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)

Comment: Thanks Andrei, unfortunately this isn't really my problem. The issue here is in displaying checkboxes for a predetermined set of options, and allowing the user to enter extra information for the options they select.