# Updating extra column in a has_many, :through table with Coffeescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, jquery-ui-sortable, has-many-through

I've got a rather simple setup here: A `Doc` model, a `Publication` model, and an `Article` model.

**doc.rb**

```
class Doc < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :article_ids,:created_at, :updated_at, :title
  has_many :publications, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :articles, :through => :publications, :order => 'publications.position'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :articles, allow_destroy: false
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :publications, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**publication.rb**

```
class Publication < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :doc_id, :article_id, :position
  belongs_to :doc
  belongs_to :article
  acts_as_list
end
```

**article.rb**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :issue, :name, :page, :image, :article_print, :video, :id
  has_many :publications
  has_many :docs, :through => :publications
end
```

The `Doc` form lets users select and order a number of articles:

```
...
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <span class="handle">[drag]</span> 
    <%= check_box_tag("doc[article_ids][]", article.id, @doc.articles.include?(article), :class => "article_chooser" ) %> 
    <a id="<%= article.id %>" class="name"><%= article.name %></a>
<% end %>
...
```

This Coffeescript saves the order on drag:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#sort_articles').sortable(
    axis: 'y'
    handle: '.handle'
    update: ->
      $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'))
  );
```

And this is the sort method in **docs_controller.rb**:

```
def sort
  Article.all.each_with_index do |id, index|
    Publication.update_all({position: index + 1}, {id: id})
  end
render nothing: true
end
```

I've followed [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists-revised) sortable lists Rails cast and it all works well until I update a `Doc` record because re-ordering isn't saved on update. I've come to the conclusion that it's because my sortable field is on the association table (i.e., `publications`), but because of the way the app works it has to be.

I've been doing some research here and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174513/rails-has-many-through-form-with-checkboxes-and-extra-field-in-the-join-model) question whose answer comes close, but because I've got a Coffeescript action saving the record in the first place it doesn't work.

Any help would be excellent, I'm really stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I struggled for a long time with this I'm putting my stupidly simple solution here. Hopefully it helps someone else.

It's as simple as deleting the old join table records on `update` before the changes are saved, i.e.:

**docs_controller.rb**

```
def update
  @doc = Doc.find(params[:id])
  @doc.publications.destroy_all
  respond_to do |format|
    if @doc.update_attributes(params[:doc])
      format.html { redirect_to share_url(@doc) }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @doc.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Boom.