# text_field for extra attribute in has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through, join

- ruby 2.1
- rails 4.2.1

I'm stuck with editing/creating a text_field of extra param in the join table.

I have 3 basic models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
  has_many :taggings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :taggings
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, through: :taggings
  has_many :taggings
end

class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :tag, counter_cache: :products_count
end
```

My permitted params so far:

```
class Admin::ProductsController < Admin::BaseController
  def product_params
    params[:product].permit(tag_ids: [], taggings_attributes: [:id, :product_id, :tag_id, :items])
  end
end
```

And, finally, the product form:

```
= form_for [:admin, @product] do |f|
  - Tag.order(:name).all.each do |tag|
    = f.check_box :tag_ids, { :multiple => true }, tag.id, nil
    = label(:product_tag_ids, tag.id, tag.name, class: 'checkbox_label')
      = tag.name

      = f.fields_for :taggings do |t|
        = t.hidden_field :tag_id, value: tag.id
        = t.text_field :items
```

I can create and save tags nicely, but, how to edit/create the "items" attribute in the join table "taggings"?

**Final Update**

A similar question and the answer were found here: [Rails has_many through form with checkboxes and extra field in the join model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174513/rails-has-many-through-form-with-checkboxes-and-extra-field-in-the-join-model)

Comment: Have you written a migration to add the attribute to to taggings?

Comment: @papirtiger Yes. I did. One of the problems is: I have duplicate records in this way on create. Once for tag_ids[] and once for taggings_attributes[:items]. I need to pass both parametres for the same record.