# rails has many through checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, has-many-through

I have three models

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :service_tasks
 has_many :tasks, through: :service_tasks

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :service_tasks, reject_if: :all_blank,allow_destroy: true
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :service_tasks
 has_many :services, through: :service_tasks

 enum kind: [:before, :after, :whole]
end

class ServiceTask < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :service
 belongs_to :task
 #attribute duration


end
```

And I didn't understand how I can make form for add or remove ServiceTask to Service with choosing Task and different duration for each ServiceTask

I tried

```
= form_for service, html: { class: "service-form" } do |form|
  = render "shared/form_errors", object: @service
  - @tasks.each do |task|
    %tr.presence-times-form__day
      %td.presence-times-form__day__weekday
        .checkbox
          = label_tag nil, class: "label" do
            = check_box_tag :task_ids, task.id,   @service.tasks.include?(task), :name => 'service[task_ids][]'
            = label_tag :task_ids, task.name
```

But can't figure how add duration for each ServiceTask

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it.
Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/835935/ok32 and [Rails has_many through form with checkboxes and extra field in the join model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174513/rails-has-many-through-form-with-checkboxes-and-extra-field-in-the-join-model)

```
Class ServicesController
 before_filter :process_service_tasks_attrs, only: [:create, :update] #_destroy param

def new
  @service = current_user.services.build

  Task.all.each do |task|
    @service.service_tasks.new(task: task) unless @service.tasks.include?(task)
  end
end

def edit
  @service = current_user.services.find(params[:id])

  Task.all.each do |task|
    @service.service_tasks.new(task: task) unless @service.tasks.include?(task)
  end

end


 private

 def process_service_tasks_attrs
  params[:service][:service_tasks_attributes].values.each do |attr|
   attr[:_destroy] = true unless attr[:task_id].present?
  end
 end

  def service_params
   params.require(:service).permit(
   ...
   service_tasks_attributes: [:duration,:task_id, :id, :_destroy]
   )
 end

end
```

and view

```
 = form.fields_for :service_tasks do |task_form|
  %tr.presence-times-form__day
    %td.presence-times-form__day__weekday
      .checkbox
        = label_tag nil, class: "label" do
          = task_form.check_box :task_id, { checked: @service.tasks.include?(task_form.object.task) }, task_form.object.task_id, nil
          = task_form.object.task.name
    %td
      = label_tag nil, class: "label" do
        = task_form.text_field :duration
```