# Checkboxes for has_many through, with additional join table attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reform, trailblazer

I have a `has_many :through` association between some models, which determine which datasets are visible on certain dashboards.

```
class Dashboard < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dashboard_datasets
  has_many :datasets, :through => :dashboard_datasets
end

class DashboardDataaset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dashboard
  belongs_to :dataset
end

class Dataset < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dashboard_datasets
  has_many :dashboards, :through => :dashboard_datasets
end
```

The form for creating a new `Dashboard` then has a simple set of checkboxes named `dataset_ids[]` to allow you to select which **pre-existing** datasets I want to be displayed on that dashboard.

```
class DashboardForm < Reform::Form
  model: :dashboard

  property :name
  property :description
  collection :dataset_ids
end
```

**So far, so simple...**

I'm now, however, looking to add an additional association to the join table, to determine the 'layout' which should be used for that dataset on that given dashboard. i.e. grid, table, list. etc

```
class Layout < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dashboard_datasets
end

class DashboardDataaset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dashboard
  belongs_to :dataset
  belongs_to :layout
end
```

I now want to adapt my dashboard form, so that in addition to the checkboxes, for each dataset checkbox which is selected, there is a select box for me to choose the layout to be used on this given association.

Where do I begin? Expand the `collection` on the form object to be richer and include more information?

Greatly appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

[Found a good example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174513/rails-has-many-through-form-with-checkboxes-and-extra-field-in-the-join-model) by [0k32](https://stackoverflow.com/users/835935/ok32)

The key pieces of information are:

- Set up a standard has_many association, factory -> factory_color -> color
- use accepts_nested_attributes_for on factory_color
- Create a temporary model list, with a model for each checkbox. (factory.all_colors)
- Use a fields_for feature where you can pass the association, and a separate    list of the models e.g. fields_for :factory_colors, @factory.all_colors do |fc| ...
- Add a before filter in the controller to set the _destroy attribute for unchecked items.